# Connection html5 geolocation to a database search query: php/mysqli

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysqli, geolocation

What I'm trying to do is show people some venues that are "relatively" nearby. I have a database with latitudes and longitudes, and I have html5 geolocation set up.

I have a simple geolocation script which works

```
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    var latlon = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;
    var img_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="
    +latlon+"&size=640x300&scale=2&zoom=14&maptype=satellite&key=MYKEY";
    document.getElementById("map").style.backgroundImage = "url('"+img_url+"')";
}
```

And another jquery/ajax like script which searches the database

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['term1'])){

    $maxlat = $_REQUEST['term1'] + 0.02;
    $minlat = $_REQUEST['term1'] - 0.02;
    $maxlong = $_REQUEST['term2'] + 0.02;
    $minlong = $_REQUEST['term2'] - 0.02;

    // Prepare a select statement
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM performance_venues WHERE performance_venue_lat > ? AND performance_venue_lat < ? AND performance_venue_long > ? AND performance_venue_long < ?";

    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $maxlat, $minlat, $maxlong, $minlong);

...etc.
```

Now all I need is a way to get the geolocation data into the search query, when the document has loaded, and to display the results in the page.

I do not need high accuracy, so I'm not gonna bother with difficult formula's and square roots of sinuses and the earth's curve. All I'm looking for is, when my document has loaded, the search query has gone to my database and has reproduced some results.

Thus far I have had no succes with the following code:

```
<script>
function searchLoc( jQuery ) {
        var inputVal1 = position.coords.longitude;
        var inputVal2 = position.coords.latitude;

        var resultDropdown = $('.result');

            $.get("nearby.php", {term1: inputVal1, term2: inputVal2}).done(function(data){
                // Display the returned data in browser
                resultDropdown.html(data);
        });
    };

$( document ).ready( searchLoc );   
</script>
```

But I have to admit that I'm a bit lost when it comes to javascript and jQuery, so I would not be surprised if I'm doing something really dumb.